# Страница входа/регистрации Stack Overflow на русском

Tags: дефект, статус-завершено, локализация, дизайн

Несколько проблем, обнаруженных на [странице входа/регистрации](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/signup) (чтобы увидеть страницу надо разлогиниться или открыть ссылку в приватном окне, как было предложено в [комментарии](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/3714/%D0%A1%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B0-%D0%B2%D1%85%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B0-%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8-stack-overflow-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D1%80%D1%83%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC#comment11971_3714)) в сообщество:

1. Сомнительный межстрочный интервал в предложении:

   [image: между строк]

   Особенно хорошо это заметно при выделении текста:

   [image: выделено между строк]
2. Вкладка регистрации почему-то называется "Отправить":

   [image: отправить регистрацию]
3. Выравнивание текста на кнопке "Отправить":

   [image: выравнивание регистрации]
4. Упомянутая выше кнопка должна иметь другой текст, например, "Зарегистрироваться" или "Регистрация".
5. Не переведен заголовок страницы входа:

   [image: заголовок страницы входа]
6. На странице [добавления логина](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/login-add) текст не помещается на кнопке:

   [image: добавить регистрац]
7. Отсутствует перевод заголовка страницы:

   [image: Add Login Credential]

Comment: _"разлогиниться"_ - открыть в приватном окне же...

Comment: @Qwertiy тогда уж _"в **новом** приватном окне"_. Хотя, это тоже не работает, если уже залогинен в существующем приватном окне.

Comment: Но зачем быть залогиненным на SO в приватном окне? о_О

Comment: @Qwertiy А собственно почему нет? Главное же, чтоб хвосты не сохранились при закрытии окна. Как я понимаю, именно в этом суть приватного режима.

Comment: Не вижу смысл прятать хвосты SO :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The remaining issues (#1, #2, #3, #5, #6) should will be fixed in the next build (2016.11.16.4198),

The missing string for #7 will be added [to Transifex here](https://www.transifex.com/stack-exchange/stack-overflow-ru/translate/#ru/%24/-1?key=33eb073721410b1ddb568333aede4d2a).

Answer (score 0):

[Tx:2426](https://www.transifex.com/stack-exchange/stack-overflow-ru/translate/#ru/$/40264196?key=d9776f0775997b2e698c6975420b5c5d)

> <s>Отправить</s> Регистрация

Похоже, на синей кнопке используется этот же текст, так что теперь выравнивание станет ещё хуже. Причина в том, что там выравнивание не по центру, а с помощью отступа от левого края.