# На странице регистрации слетает кнопка Регистрация

Tags: дефект, регистрация

Когда на странице [регистрации](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/signup) нажать **больше способов входа**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

то кнопка **Регистрация** становится такой

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Чтобы это исправить, нужно в CSS дописать:

```
#signup-page #login-form input {
    padding: 12px 0;
}
```

Comment: Старая [проблема](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/3886/176217)

Comment: @alexolut, прошу прощения, не увидел. Мне тогда закрывать?

Comment: Тот значится как исправленный, но я вот нашел свой [репорт](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/302715/339911) на MSE, затрагивающий локализованные сайты.